# How to properly annotate dataclasses with attributes that are not initialized?

Tags: python, annotations, mypy, typing

Given the following code:

```py
from typing import Self
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    var: float = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self: Self) -> None:
        self.var = True
```

My expection is that the line `self.var = True` should produce an error because the wrong type is assigned to `self.var`. However, type checkers like mypy or pyright cannot find any issues. Is it possible to annotate the dataclass in a way that the wrong assignment is detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are important here:

- first: `__post_init__` is run after an object is initialised, therefore you wouldn't get any runtime error just by defining a class, but after initialising an object via `MyClass()`
- second: This is an issue of coercion in python - if you pass data of a "compatible type", it will be accepted as a possible value even if it doesn't exactly match requested type. In this case the value `True` can be represented as float value `1.0`.

---

One of the ways to force the check you want is provided by [Pydantic Dataclasses](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/dataclasses/) and [Strict types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#strict-types).

Short example:

```
from dataclasses import field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import StrictFloat


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    var: StrictFloat = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        self.var = True
```

When calling `MyClass()`, you will get an error:

```
my_class = MyClass()
```

Output:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyClass
var
  value is not a valid float (type=type_error.float)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't realize that I actually receive an error if I change for example the 7th line to `var: str = field(init=False)`. The first part does not seem to be correct, mypy complains even if i do not create an instance of MyClass. Is there a way to enforce that _strictness_ with python standard library methods only?

Comment: The innit and post innit methods are definitely only executed after you create an object, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing). 

I should have been clearer in my response: any type hinting tool (IDEs, mypy, etc.) will "complain"/hint about assignment of unexpected type into a variable. But it won't necessarily cause a runtime error, it will only highlight the issue in your editor. What happens with this `pydantic` exmaple is, that the code will actually fail if you try to run it.

Comment: As for the enforcement with the standard library - sadly that is not possible out of the box, because Python is a dynamically typed language. 
If you want static type checking you need to use some plugin/library on top of python, and if you want runtime errors due to mismatched types you again need to use a library or implement some type-checking yourself.